# How do I write an SQL query to extract related records from a single table?

Tags: sql

I have a table that is basically a directory of people - name, address, etc. I want to retrieve all records with a specific last name (like Smith), plus all other records of people with the same address as those Smiths who may not be a Smith. For example, if John Smith lives at 123 Main Street, I want to retrieve the records for anyone living at 123 Main Street even if their name isn't Smith (like a wife who uses her family name).

I've tried the following in SQLite without success:

```
select t1.Name_Last, t1.Name_First, t1.Residence_Address_Line_1 from residents T1
where (t1.name_last like "smith")  
union
select t2.Name_Last, t2.Name_First, t2.Residence_Address_Line_1 from residents T2
Where T1.Residence_Address_Line_1 like T2.Residence_Address_Line_1
order by Residence_Address_Line_1;
```

The error I get is: no such column: T1.Residence_Address_Line_1

Comment: The UNION's second SELECT has no access to the first SELECT's tables/columns.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IN statement, or use a CTE such as this example:

Set-up your data:

```
create table residents (
last_name varchar(20), 
addr_line_1 varchar(20)
);

insert into residents values 
('smith', '123 main st'),
('jones', '123 main st'), 
('chang', '123 main street');
```

CTE Query:

```
with target_address as (
  select distinct addr_line_1
  from residents
  where last_name = 'smith'
  )
select r.*
from residents r
join target_address t
  on r.addr_line_1 = t.addr_line_1;
```

Output:

| last_name | addr_line_1 |
| --- | --- |
| smith | 123 main st |
| jones | 123 main st |

Alternative, IN statement:

```
select *
from residents 
where addr_line_1 in (
  select distinct addr_line_1
  from residents
  where last_name = 'smith')
```